# $product->getPrice() override for configurable products

Tags: configurable-product, price, ce-1.9.0.1

I would like to recode `$product->getPrice()` of a simple product, in case it's based on a configurable product, to get its attribute setup and prices and add to base price.

I thought about maintaining the above invocation so same method call is used for simple products not based on configurable too.

What would be a good way to do that regarding files to change ?

Thanks.